# Update a field in mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I have this code here:

```
$userid = Secure($_POST[ 'username' ]);
$user = $db->where('username', $userid)->getOne('users',array('id','web_device_id','is_pro'));
$is_user_matches = $db->where('user_id', $user['id'])->where('like_userid', self::ActiveUser()->id)->getOne('likes', array('id'));
$id              = $db->where('user_id', self::ActiveUser()->id)->where('like_userid', $user['id'])->getValue('likes', 'id');
$saved           = false;

if ($id > 0) {
    $saved = $db->where('id', $id)->update('likes', array(
        'user_id' => self::ActiveUser()->id,
        'like_userid' => $user['id'],
        'is_like' => 1,
        'is_dislike' => 0,
        'created_at' => date('Y-m-d H:i:s')
    ));
} else {
    if(isUserLiked($user['id']) === false) {
        $saved = $db->insert('likes', array(
            'user_id' => self::ActiveUser()->id,
            'like_userid' => $user['id'],
            'is_like' => 1,
            'is_dislike' => 0,
            'created_at' => date('Y-m-d H:i:s')
        ));
        
    }
}
```

These are the actions that occur when a user presses the LIKE button!
Now, my question is. How can I add in addition to these codes, an UPDATE for a table in mysql?
I would like that when a user gives a Like to a person, he will count automatically.

```
    mysql_query("
        UPDATE users 
        SET likes = likes + 1
        WHERE id = '".$user['id']."'
    ");
```

I tried to add this code but I couldn't. I don't think I'm adding it where it should be. Can you show me an example please?

Comment: `mysql_query` should never be used. Use the framework you are using. Also use parameterized queries, SQL shouldn't have variables in it.

Comment: And in this case, can you give me an example please?

Comment: I dont know what you are using. Tag the framework

Comment: I am using PHP and SQL

Comment: Those are two languages, and one very broad. Your SQL is MySQL but we need to know what `$db` is.